# Unable to concatenate videos due to identical MOOV atoms

Tags: ffmpeg

I am cutting out segments from a long mp4 file and then rejoining parts of them. However, since FFMPEG apparently keeps the same MOOV atom for the trimmed files as the original, it looks to FFMPEG that the trimmed videos are all identical since they all have the same MOOV atom, and therefore only uses the first segment when trying to join the videos. Is there a way around this? Unfortunately since FFMPEG is embedded in an Android app, I can only use version 0.11.

Comment: so don't use mp4 for your temporary files?  mkv works well, and if you're ONLY using ffmpeg, try nut for scratch files if you ever run into a problem with mkv.  (e.g. nut worked for `-c:v rawvideo` where mkv didn't, for me, since mkv didn't have a type ID for that kind of rawvideo.)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact details of your workflow it is hard to answer this question, so more information would be greatly helpful.

One approach would be to use raw video during your "joining" phase of the algo to strip the moov atom. The final step would be to convert your concat'ed raw video back into mp4.

Comment: Thank you.  Basically it was for an app (that I'm no longer working on) that allowed you to record a long video and then mark where you wanted to strip out content. Imagine recording a football game for instance, with a lot of stops and starts in action and you just want to strip out the filler and have a video with only the action.

Comment: I see. If you are no longer interested in an answer, then it is a good idea to delete your question.

Comment: I'm still curious to see if there's an actual answer to this question :). Who knows what the future holds.